# How can I test my test values using a common tolerance?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, googletest

In the following tests, `TestParticleForce` succeeds, but `TestParticleKineticEnergy` fails if both of them are use the same precision `0.00001`.

As far as I understand, `EXPECT_NEAR(val1, val2, 0.00001);` means the test framework should consider only five digits after the decimal. Is that correct? If so, why does it fail?

How can I test my test values using a common tolerance?

**test_particles.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "header.h"

TEST(TestParticle, TestParticleKineticEnergy)
{
    Particle particle(1, Constants::ATOMIC_MASS,
        Constants::EPSILON, Constants::SIGMA,
        Constants::KB, Vec3(1, 1, 1), Vec3(1, 1, 1));

    real kinetic = particle.getKineticEnergy();

    EXPECT_NEAR(29.9625, kinetic, 0.01);
}

TEST(TestParticle, TestParticleForce)
{
    Particle particle(1, Constants::ATOMIC_MASS,
        Constants::EPSILON, Constants::SIGMA,
        Constants::KB, Vec3(1, 1, 1),
        Vec3(1, 1, 1));
    Particle other(1, Constants::ATOMIC_MASS,
        Constants::EPSILON, Constants::SIGMA,
        Constants::KB, Vec3(0, 0, 0),
        Vec3(1, 1, 1));

    Vec3 force = particle.getForce(other);

    EXPECT_NEAR(-0.00044463402, force.x, 0.00001);
    EXPECT_NEAR(-0.00044463402, force.y, 0.00001);
    EXPECT_NEAR(-0.00044463402, force.z, 0.00001);
}
```

Comment: "means the test framework should consider only five digits after the decimal", not really, `EXPECT_NEAR` means that `abs(target - value)` does not exceed given tolerance. In your case it exceeds.

Answer (score 1):

It means it only accepts values within the specified range  `[-0.00011127498 - 0.00001,-0.00011127498 + 0.00001]`.
And  -0.00022251079577138472 < -0.00012127498. If the results are correct, consider using a larger tolerance.

Comment: Sorry we don't have your source files. Are there any error messages?

Comment: there is no error message.

Comment: So did your unit test pass? Or have other questions? Different calculation methods should have different tolerance values.